# Databinding Swing Eclipse beansbinding-1.2.1.jar WindowBuilderPro

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, data-binding, windowbuilder

I`m trying to make a new GUI with Databinding under Eclipse IDE with the WindowBuilder.
First I added the beansbinding-1.2.1.jar to the project and got the Bindings Tab for the WindowBuilder.

I created a Bean (JavaBean), a Main Class (Run) and two different JFrames (LabelWindow and TextFieldWindow). All down below in the Post.
In the LabelWindow I used a JLabel to show the Data from the Bean (Name: "Foo"). Thats working perfect. If I change the Data in the bean the data in that JLabel is also changing and if I change the data in that JLabel the Bean is also changed.

In the TextFieldWindow I used a JTextField to show the Data from the Bean. And thats not working like the JLabel. The Gui shows the Data from the Bean "Foo" and if I change the Beans Value it also apears in the JTextField. Thats working.
But if I change the Value of the JTextField the Beans value doesn`t change.

The whole JFrame is generated by the "Swing Automatic Databinding Wizard" from the WindowBuilder Plugin and with JLabel it works, with JTextField it works only in one direction.

Can somebody tell me whats wrong and how to fix this (I would prefer a way with the WindowBuilder / Bindingtab, I just don`t wanna change much by hand).

Here is my Code:

**JavaBean.java**

```
package def;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class JavaBean {
    private String name = "Foo";
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        String oldValue = this.name;
        this.name = name;
        pcs.firePropertyChange("name", oldValue, name);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(pcl);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(pcl);
    }
}
```

**Run.java**

```
package def;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Switch these two Versions to Test either the Label Version or the TextField Version
        //EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> new LabelWindow().setVisible(true));
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> new TextFieldWindow().setVisible(true));
    }

}
```

**LabelWindow.java**

```
package def;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding;
import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty;
import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup;
import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings;

public class LabelWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BindingGroup m_bindingGroup;
    private JPanel m_contentPane;
    private JavaBean javaBean = new JavaBean();
    private JLabel nameJLabel;

    public LabelWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        m_contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(m_contentPane);
        //
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0 };
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4 };
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0E-4 };
        m_contentPane.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        GridBagConstraints labelGbc_0 = new GridBagConstraints();
        labelGbc_0.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        labelGbc_0.gridx = 0;
        labelGbc_0.gridy = 0;
        m_contentPane.add(nameLabel, labelGbc_0);

        nameJLabel = new JLabel();
        GridBagConstraints componentGbc_0 = new GridBagConstraints();
        componentGbc_0.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
        componentGbc_0.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        componentGbc_0.gridx = 1;
        componentGbc_0.gridy = 0;
        m_contentPane.add(nameJLabel, componentGbc_0);

        if (javaBean != null) {
            m_bindingGroup = initDataBindings();
        }
    }

    protected BindingGroup initDataBindings() {
        BeanProperty<JavaBean, String> nameProperty = BeanProperty.create("name");
        BeanProperty<JLabel, String> textProperty = BeanProperty.create("text");
        AutoBinding<JavaBean, String, JLabel, String> autoBinding = Bindings
                .createAutoBinding(AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, javaBean, nameProperty, nameJLabel,
                        textProperty);
        autoBinding.bind();
        //
        BindingGroup bindingGroup = new BindingGroup();
        bindingGroup.addBinding(autoBinding);
        //
        return bindingGroup;
    }
}
```

**TextFieldWindow.java**

```
package def;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding;
import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty;
import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup;
import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings;

public class TextFieldWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BindingGroup m_bindingGroup;
    private JPanel m_contentPane;
    private JavaBean javaBean = new JavaBean();
    private JTextField nameJTextField;

    public TextFieldWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        m_contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(m_contentPane);
        //
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0 };
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4 };
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0E-4 };
        m_contentPane.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        GridBagConstraints labelGbc_0 = new GridBagConstraints();
        labelGbc_0.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        labelGbc_0.gridx = 0;
        labelGbc_0.gridy = 0;
        m_contentPane.add(nameLabel, labelGbc_0);

        nameJTextField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints componentGbc_0 = new GridBagConstraints();
        componentGbc_0.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);
        componentGbc_0.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        componentGbc_0.gridx = 1;
        componentGbc_0.gridy = 0;
        m_contentPane.add(nameJTextField, componentGbc_0);

        if (javaBean != null) {
            m_bindingGroup = initDataBindings();
        }
    }

    protected BindingGroup initDataBindings() {
        BeanProperty<JavaBean, String> nameProperty = BeanProperty.create("name");
        BeanProperty<JTextField, String> textProperty = BeanProperty.create("text");
        AutoBinding<JavaBean, String, JTextField, String> autoBinding = Bindings
                .createAutoBinding(AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, javaBean, nameProperty, nameJTextField,
                        textProperty);
        autoBinding.bind();
        //
        BindingGroup bindingGroup = new BindingGroup();
        bindingGroup.addBinding(autoBinding);
        //
        return bindingGroup;
    }

    public JavaBean getJavaBean() {
        return javaBean;
    }

    public void setJavaBean(JavaBean newJavaBean) {
        setJavaBean(newJavaBean, true);
    }

    public void setJavaBean(JavaBean newJavaBean, boolean update) {
        javaBean = newJavaBean;
        if (update) {
            if (m_bindingGroup != null) {
                m_bindingGroup.unbind();
                m_bindingGroup = null;
            }
            if (javaBean != null) {
                m_bindingGroup = initDataBindings();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem in two different instances of JavaBean class (JavaBean javaBean = new JavaBean() in TextFieldWindow and in LabelWindow). Try to create one instance of JavaBean in main() method and pass it throw constructors into *Window.

Comment: Its just a showcase of both Versions in a single start. I changed the original Post to make that clear and command out the label version (feel free to switch between them).

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Run` you are creating two top-level containers. I haven't run your posted code but I've never tried creating two top-level containers in one application. I suggest creating one `JFrame` that contains both the `JLabel` and the `JTextField`. Is there a reason why you didn't?

Comment: Its just to show in one run that it works with the Label version and in the TextField version it does not. You can only run one version test it and then run the other and test that one. It doesn`t change the result. I edited the Question to make that clear.